# Why does hdparm return 2 differing results when AHCI is enabled and disabled?

Tags: hard-disk, hardware, sata, hdparm

When invoking the `hdparm` command to securely erase devices e.g. ATA SECURE ERASE, the output `hdparm -I /dev/sda` and `hdparm -I /dev/sdb` differ with AHCI enabled and disabled.

Both devices are SATA hard drives.

**Establishing state**

1. Both /dev/sda and /dev/sdb have the data & power cable plugged in
2. The device boots with a Linux LiveCD
3. AHCI is disabled
4. When the command `hdparm -I /dev/sda` and `hdparm -I /dev/sdb` is run, both drives appear as frozen.

The following steps are taken in an attempt to 'unfreeze' the drive.

1. Both /dev/sda and /dev/sdb only have the data cable plugged in. The power cable is not plugged in.
2. AHCI remains disabled.
3. Boot the device with a Linux LiveCD.
4. Once booted, both the devices have the power cables plugged in.
5. When the command `hdparm -I /dev/sda` and `hdparm -I /dev/sdb` is run, the former displays a frozen state and the latter as not frozen.

The following steps are taken to 'unfreeze' /dev/sda

1. The data cable remains plugged in for /dev/sda
2. AHCI is enabled.
3. Boot the device with a Linux LiveCD
4. Once booted, the power cable is plugged into /dev/sda
5. When the command `hdparm -I /dev/sda` is run, the drive is no longer frozen.

Why would enabling AHCI affect /dev/sda whist disabling AHCI not affect /dev/sdb when 'unfreezing' the devices?

Comment: Random guess: BIOS does something differently, maybe a SATA reset would do similar. AHCI on is usually a better choice anyway (at least if the alternative is some pre-AHCI emulation).